# Make user choosing how many threads he want the program to use

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'd like to make a program that read each line of a .txt file do something with each line.

I would like to user to be able to choose threads so if he choose for example 10 threads so the program will be able to do something on 10 lines at the same time.

Let say the text file contains for example 1 000 000 lines, how must I do ?

This is what I actually have for reading the lines one by one :

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(accounts);
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    // Start a thread, but maximum 10 threads at the same if the user input is 10, for example.
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't absolutely control the number of threads. The number used depends on the number available and other factors. But you can limit the number of threads by specifying the maximum number to use.

Using [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach%60%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.1):

```
var options = new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5};
Parallel.ForEach(lines, options, line =>
{
    // do something with each line
});
```

`MaxDegreeOfParellelism` doesn't tell the whole story, though. It merely limits the number of threads. The threads used come from the managed thread pool. The number of threads available for starting new tasks can be set using `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads` and `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads`.

But that still doesn't tell the whole story. The number of concurrent operations that can be performed is limited by your number of CPU cores. It also depends on what those operations do. For example, no matter how many threads you have running they can't all write to the disk at the same time. Increasing the number of threads beyond a certain point may decrease performance.

So while it's interesting to experiment with, in most scenarios it's very unlikely that the user of a program would know how many threads should run concurrently.

And this is only one way to accomplish multithreading. `Parellel.ForEach` is a convenience for when you have an `IEnumerable` (like the array of lines read from the file) and want to execute them in parallel.

One more factor to take into account is that when you perform operations in parallel you can't guarantee the sequence in which they will execute. They may appear to run FIFO, but then you'll run it again and they won't.

Comment: Hello and thanks a lot, must I put this code into my foreach or replace my foreach ? Thanks.

Comment: This would replace your foreach.

Answer (score 2):

Parallel.ForEach will run each loop instance in its own thread, and will also allow you to set the MaxDegreeOfParallelism (# of threads) to whatever you want.

```
        Parallel.ForEach(lines, new ParallelOptions{ MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, line =>
        {
            // do stuff with line
        });
```

Comment: Hello and thanks a lot, must I put this code into my foreach or replace my foreach ? Thanks.

Comment: This is a replacement for your foreach loop that will run each one of the loops on its own thread.